# Sensitivity of hierarchical clustering solution in r

Tags: r, vegan, hclust

I'm using hierarchical clustering to pull out a set number of clusters from a dataset. My objective is to test how robust the clustering solution is when I reduce the amount of data used (and potentially the variables included). I think this means subsampling the data, and then making a new distance matrix, and a new dendrogram each time I adjust something. One way I can think to measure sensitivity of the clustering solution is to compare the cluster centroids made with full data to those made with a subset of the data, I could do this by projecting them in PCoA space and calculating distance between cluster centroids (in PCoA space). This is close to what the *betadisper* function from package vegan does (apart from it calculates distance of points in the cluster to the centroid). However, my problem is that if I have created different distance matrices when subsampling, then the PCoA space will be different between subsample runs, and therefore non-comparable. Is it possible to simply standardise the PCoA space from different subsample runs to make them comparable?

Any pointers or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated,

Mark

```
library(vegan)

# my data has categorial variables so I'll use gower with the iris dataset for example
mydist<-dist(iris[,1:4])
# Pull, out 3 clusters
hc_av<-hclust(d=mydist, method='average')
my_cut<-cutree(hc_av, 3)
# calc distance to cluster centre
mod<-betadisper(mydist, my_cut)
mod
plot(mod)

# randomly remove 5% of data and recalc as above - this would be bootstrapped

mydist2<-dist(iris[sort(sample(1:150, 145)),1:4])
# Pull, out 3 clusters
hc_av2<-hclust(d=mydist2, method='average')
my_cut2<-cutree(hc_av2, 3)
# calc distance to cluster centre
mod2<-betadisper(mydist2, my_cut2)
mod2
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(mod, main='full model'); plot(mod2, main='subset')
# How can I to calculate the distance each cluster centroid has moved when 
subsampling the data relative to the full model?
```

Comment: I suggest you have a look at this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#comparing-two-dendrograms

Comment: PCoA will reproduce original distances when scaled appropriately with eigenvalues (with a slight complication when you have negative eigenvalues). This means that *distances* between cluster centroids are comparable among 95% subsamples as long as you can identify "same" clusters among cluster runs.

Comment: Thanks Tal and Jari - apologies for my slow reply, I've had a look at dendextend, and can certainly see it's use, but for my particular problem I couldn't figure out how I would compare dendrograms created with different amounts of data? Jari, so I understand correctly are you saying that I can simply calculate the difference between the centroid position of the 100% model and centroid position of the 95% model? e.g. using the code above: `scores(mod)$centroids[1,]-scores(mod2)$centroids[1,]`

Comment: @Jari actually I suppose calculating difference between centroids using all PCoA axes would be preferable to just the first two  e.g. `dist(rbind(mod$centroids[1,], mod2$centroids[1,]))` However, would I need to weight the calculation knowing that the first few axes explain a lot more than the later ones?